# android inter thread com without sharing

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to do some inter thread communication. If I understood correctly some eample I have read there is always a global variabal (like Handler) that both threads are sharing.
I need my threads com to be done without sharing any objects.

Is it possible?

10xs,
Nahum

Comment: How can I do inter thread com without sharing objeccts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do inter-thread communication with Handler. I hope you are not confusing inter-thread communication with Inter Process Communication(IPC).

Comment: 10xs. I might didn't understand the example that I saw but doesn't the threads share the handler?

Comment: No they exactly do not share the handler but they are used in communication between threads in a different way.